# How to select variables in one to many relationship table one by one

Tags: php

My code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, images.image_url

FROM tmdb_movies

JOIN images ON images.images_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,images.image_url");

 // Then fire it up
 $stmt->execute();
 // Pick up the result as an array
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
 for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){

 echo'
  '.$result[$x]["movie_title"].' - <img src="'.$result[$x]["image_url"].'"/>
  ';

}
```

> Example: How it Echo Data

```
The Dark Knight: - <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/>
The Dark Knight: - <img src="fdfgfdd.jpg"/>
The Dark Knight: - <img src="sdfs.jpg"/>
```

> How I Want It to echo data

```
The Dark Knight -  <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/> <img src="fdfgfdd.jpg"/> <img src="sdfs.jpg"/>
```

I am using an One To Many Relationship SQL table, Two tables:

**tmdb_movies** and **images**

Answer (score 1):

You can assign last executed title in one variable then check that every time. Change below code in `for` loop:

```
$last_title = "";
for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){
      if($last_title != $result[$x]["movie_title"])
      {
            $last_title = $result[$x]["movie_title"];
            echo $last_title.' - <img src="'.$result[$x]["image_url"].'"/>';
      }
      else
            echo '<img src="'.$result[$x]["image_url"].'"/>';
}
```

Comment: This is just an example, i have more data in the page other than just movie title. This is not at all a good idea bro